# SQLite How to open an sqlite database file using command line `sqlite`?

Tags: sqlite

i using this:

> apt-get install sqlite
>
> sqlite data.db

but i got this:

> Unable to open database "data/Garfielt.db": file is encrypted or is
> not a database

Why? If it's encrypt, how to type command?

Comment: Are you sure that `data/Garfielt.db` is a (valid) sqlite database in the first place?

Comment: This appears to be the error message from a different command, `sqlite data/Garfielt.db` --> unclear what you're asking

Comment: What is the output of `file data/Garfielt.db`?

Comment: root@iZ287xcvr93Z:~/my_web_site/GarfieltBlog-webpy# file data/Garfielt.db 
data/Garfielt.db: SQLite 3.x database